# Child element inheriting Parent styling

Tags: html, css

I have three elements.

The CSS:

```
#parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 580px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

#child img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <img/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, essentially, if an image is smaller than 580px (width) I want it to be centered in the parent element. But, for some reason, when I set the width of the Child to auto, it fills the entire width of the Parent element. I want it to be the width of the photo so that it can be centered in the Parent div. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to center the image within its parent image try this:

```
#child img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

No need to adjust the width of the image with css.

Answer (score 0):

Set the display of the child `<div>` to `inline-block` and then set the parent's `text-align` to `center`:

```
#parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 580px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
}

#child {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vGgYK/)